# Wildcard SSL cert warning of insecure content across sub domains

Tags: centos, ssl

I have a wildcard SSL certificate installed on various servers for different sub-domains.

When looking at any pages or other content directly all browsers are happy with the certificate.

But if I load a page on site 1 that includes content from site 2 say an image then the padlock breaks in the browser and warns about mixed content. This happens on all browsers.

These are the SSL settings being used:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv3 -SSLv2 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

> But if I load a page on site 1 that includes content from site 2 say an image then the padlock breaks in the browser and warns about mixed content.

This is not a problem of using content across domains, but across protocols. Mixed content means that you try to include resources via HTTP (unencrypted) on a HTTPS (encrypted) site, no matter if this is the same host or a different host. This warning is because some of the content is protected while the other is not and thus can be changed from a man-in-the-middle. This effectively can make the protection from the original moot.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is warning about mixed domains because you're using mixed domains. The fact that they happen to use the same wildcard certificate is not relevant here. Everything is working the way it's supposed to. The fix is to not use mixed domains on your SSL websites.